# Associated primes of the localization of a Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm reading the following proof in Matsumura:

[image]

I understand everything except for the second to last sentence "... and it follows that there exists some $t\in S$ such that $\mathfrak{p}=\text{ann}_A(tx)$." Can someone spell this out for me? It's likely obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are more details:

Let $\,a_1,\dots a_n\,$ a system of generators for $\mathfrak p$. Each of these generators kills the canonical image of $x$ in $S^{-1}M$, so there exists elements $s_i\in S$ such that $a_i s_ix=0$.

Now set $t=s_1\dotsm s_n$. We have $a_i(tx)=0,\;i=1,\dots, n$, whence $\mathfrak p(tx)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $r\in\newcommand{\pp}{\mathfrak{p}}\pp$, then $r\frac{x}{1}=0$ in $M_S$, so there is $t_r\in S$ such that $t_rrx=0$. Since $\pp$ is finitely generated, we can let $t$ be the product of $t_r$ for all generators $r$ of $\mathfrak{p}$. Then for this $t$, $\newcommand{\ann}{\operatorname{ann}}\pp\subseteq\ann_A(tx)$, and $\ann_A(tx)\subseteq \ann_{A_S}(tx)=\ann_{A_S}(x)=P$, so $\ann_A(tx) \subseteq P\cap A =\pp$. Hence $\pp=\ann_A(tx)$.